# LocalStorage не сохраняется значение

Tags: localstorage

firefox 67.0.3 (android) 
firefox 68.0b14 (android) 
(opera 52.4.2517.140781 (android)) 
в других 20 браузерах проблемы нет.

Написал простой пример. 
В нём видно текущее значение 'LS'. 
Зашли нажали в монитор. 
Значение 'LS' изменилось. 
Закрыли браузер - открыли а значение 'LS' не сохранилось.

https://codepen.io/Pavel_V/pen/xoQwqr

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta name="copyright" content="">
      <meta name="keywords"    content=""/>
      <meta name="description" content="localstprage"/>
      <title>localstoragetest</title>
      <style>
          *{margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
          #iphone, #android{font-size: 28px;}
          #del{width: 50px; height: 50px; float: right; background-color: green;}
      </style>
      <script>
          window.addEventListener('click', function(e)
          {
             "use strict";
             var id = e.target.id;      
             var iphone = document.getElementById("iphone");   
             var cur_LS = localStorage.getItem("test");        
             if (cur_LS === "123") {localStorage.setItem("test","ABC");}   
             if (cur_LS === "ABC") {localStorage.setItem("test","123");}
             if (cur_LS === null) {localStorage.setItem("test","ABC");}     
             if (id === "del") {localStorage.removeItem("test");}   
             cur_LS = localStorage.getItem("test"); 
             iphone.textContent = "set_new = "+cur_LS;  
          });

          window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() 
          { 
             "use strict"; 
             var android = document.getElementById("android");   
             var cur_LS = localStorage.getItem("test"); 
             android.textContent = "read "+cur_LS;  
          });
      </script>
</head> 
<body>  
       <div><span id="android">read</span></div>
       <div><span id="iphone">new</span></div>  
       <div id="del">DEL_LS</div>
</body>         
</html>
```

Comment: отредактировать вопрос можно с помощью кнопки [edit] под вопросом

Comment: Проверил в Opera 52.4.2517.140781 на своём Android 6.0.1 — всё сохраняется

Comment: у меня 8 адроид на Honor 8. спасибо за обратную связь. а Вы страницу не обновляли прежде чем закрыть браузер? если обновляю стр то может сохранится. у меня такое поведение в 2-х браузерах стабильное(

Comment: проверял ещё на этом ресурсе https://mdn.github.io/dom-examples/web-storage/ И выявлена следующая закономерность 1) данные не сохраняются если закрыть браузер и оставить открытой вкладку. 2) данные сохраняются если закрыть сначала вкладку потом закрыть браузер. 3) данные сохраняются если обновить страницу после изменения значений. Поддержка Opera и Firefox наверно не поможет(

Comment: на данный момент есть такое решение - Если перед закрытием подождать что то около 3-5 секунд то данные сохраняются.